# Unable to connect to device via react-native-ble-plx

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, react-native-ble-plx

I am trying to connect to a ble device using [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) module and below is my code for creating a connection:-

```
           console.log("device id is ", device.id) 
          manager.connectToDevice(device.id).then(mydevice=>{
              console.log("connected device is +++++++++++++++++++++",mydevice)
            }).catch(err=>{
              console.log("manager connection err",err)
            })
```

On executing the code I got below response(catch block is getting excecuted every time):-

```
device id is  3C:11:92:6B:51:8B
manager connection err [BleError: Device 3C:11:92:6B:51:8B was disconnected]
```

What should I do to make connection with particular device

Comment: Can you connect to the device using a generic BLE scanner such as nRF Connect?

Comment: Got an error :-  Error 133(0x85): GATT ERROR : Disconnected

Comment: You will find many questions about the well known GATT error 133 on stackoverflow. Usually just trying again works but there might be a problem with the device you want to connect to